# Use JS to detect when textbox has a value and a radiobuttonlist has a selected index

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, textbox, radiobuttonlist

I have a GridView whose second to last column contains a Textbox (which is filled by a jQueryUI DatePicker widget) and a RadioButtonList. Also, the last column has an Image of a check (similar to stackoverflow's "answered" and "unanswered" check.)

What I need is to be able to detect, preferably using Javascript, when the user has changed the value of the textbox to something (a date in my case) and has selected a radio button and then change the image source from an empty checkmark to a colored checkmark (once again, similar to the answer check in stackoverflow.) Also, if the user deletes all text from the textbox, I need to change the image source back to the empty checkmark. Oh, and I would also need to changed the Alternate Text of the Image as well.

**My Gridview**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBlah" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                ...       
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate> 
                        <asp:Label ID="warrantyDateHeader" Text="Warranty Date" ToolTip="Choose a date..." runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtWarrantyDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" />
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblWarrantyDate" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Start" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="End" />
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgRowChecked" ImageUrl="~/images/check-empty.png" AlternateText="Not Selected"  runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**UPDATE**

This ended up being the best solution, using the answer that was given.

```
var dateStatus = 0 // global variable
var WarrantyStatus = 0 // global variable
$(".datepicker").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        dateStatus = 0;
        $(".chkSerialNumber").removeClass("check-filled").addClass("check-empty");
    }
    else {
        dateStatus = 1;
        if (WarrantyStatus > 0) {
            $(".chkSerialNumber").addClass("check-filled").removeClass("check-empty");
        }
    }
});
$(".rbl").change(function () {
    WarrantyStatus = 1;
    if (dateStatus = 1) {
        $(".chkSerialNumber").addClass("check-filled").removeClass("check-empty");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm asuming you are not implementing multiple edits inside your gridview. So here is the jQuery code which will test for the length in your date textbox.

I would suggest you to make the image as CSS class something like this:

```
div.check-empty {
    background: url("/images/check-empty.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 11px;
    width: 55px;
}

div.checked-green {
    background: url("/images/check-green.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 11px;
    width: 55px;
}
```

and provide this inside the gridview as default like this:

```
<div class="check-empty"></div>
```

The reason for above is that you can manipulate the image using jQuery dynamically.

So the rest of the code goes like this:

1. For checking the date textbox to contain some value:

   ```
   var dateStatus = 0 // global variable
   var WarrantyStatus = 0 // global variable

   $('.datepicker').blur(function() 
   {       
      if($(this).val().length == 0)
        dateStatus = 0;
      else
       {
        dateStatus = 1;
        if(WarrantyStatus != 0)
         $(".check-empty").addClass("checked-green");
       }

    }
   ```
2. For checking if user has changed the radio button:

   ```
   $("rblWarrantyDate").change(function()
   {
      if ($(this).val() == '1') 
      {
         WarrantyStatus = 1;
         if(dateStatus != 0)
         $(".check-empty").addClass("checked-green");
      }
      else
          WarrantyStatus = 0;
   });
   ```

Comment: This seems to work only if the user picks the date from the DateTimePicker twice. The reason is, the .blur event fires when the DateTimePicker widget is clicked and happens before the textboxes value changes to the date. I attempted to use the .change event but that did not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't edit the above comment any longer, but, it seems that the textbox.change event is firing as needed. But, for some reason the radiobuttonlist.change event is no longer firing.

Comment: I got all of this to finally work. Thanks Sayed for the answer. See my update above to see the final solution used (along with the css classes you gave in your solution).

Comment: I do have an issue now. Since these controls are stored inside of a GridView, I need to get the row index of the row that contains said controls and only change that checkmark. As of now, it changes all of the .chkSerialNumber divs' classes to check-filled.

Comment: I actually didn't tested this code... just wrote like a hint for you.... Anyways glad that you made it working... thank you for providing the question.. I recalled my jQuery... Also +1 as well...